# How to set quickbase permissions to add records , Edit records

Tags: php, codeigniter, quickbase

*quickbase error response:*

I am using 'Quickbase' database integration with "codeigniter" . when i add records to it show error code 3  i.e.  "insufficent" permissions . can any one help  i am new to "quickbase".

respose from quickbase:

```
 SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [action] => API_AddRecord
    [errcode] => 3
    [errtext] => Insufficient permissions
    [errdetail] => Oops.  You don't have permission to access that page
    [username] => tbd1@brightline.com
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the user that you're using to API_Authenticate to Quickbase has insufficient permission to add a record to the table.

From within Quickbase, click on Users and verify the role associated with the user. From within the role you can view/modify the permissions that are applied to any user with that role.